# Why I'm getting nan at the output?

Tags: c++, nan

Beginner here.

I'm doing a booking system for a travel agency. Everything is fine except the calculation of  `totalSales` . I believe it is some kind of logical error for calculating `totalSales`.

How do I solve this. This Program must contains Selection, Loop, and Functions. Please make it easy to understand for me because for this semester, I only learn about the 3 topics I mentioned above.

Also, about the package counter (`line 56`), can I make it as a function instead of being in the `main`?
I had tried make it as function but it was a failure then I decided to put in `main` function.

Thank You in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string packageName(char);
double calcPrice(char, char, int, int);
double calcTax(double);
double calcDisc(double, double);
double calcTotalPrice(double, double, double);
void displayReceipt(double, double, double, double, string);

void displaySaleSummary(int, int, int, double);

char pCode, meals, decision;
int numAdult, numChild;
string name;

// main function
int main()
{

    double netPrice, taxPrice, discPrice, totalSales, totalPrice;
    int countA = 0, countB = 0, countC = 0;
    string pName;

    //sentinel controlled loop starts here
    while (decision != 'N' && decision != 'n') {

        cout << "\n\t\t\t\tAI TRAVEL AGENCY\n\n";
        cout << "\t\t A. Langkawi Island   \t\t Adult : RM 250 \t Child : RM 200 \n";
        cout << "\t\t B. Pangkor Island    \t\t Adult : RM 350 \t Child : RM 300 \n";
        cout << "\t\t C. Perhentian Island \t\t Adult : RM 450 \t Child : RM 400 \n\n";

        cout << "\t\t Add Meals to the package  \t Adult : RM 100 \t Child : RM 50\n\n\n";

        cout << "Enter customer's name : ";
        cin >> ws;
        getline(cin, name);

        cout << "Enter package code : ";
        cin >> pCode;

        cout << "Enter number of Adult : ";
        cin >> numAdult;

        cout << "Enter number of Children : ";
        cin >> numChild;

        cout << "Meals (Y/N) : ";
        cin >> meals;

        displayReceipt(netPrice, taxPrice, discPrice, totalPrice, pName);

        // this if-else statements counts how many repititions for each selected package
        if (pCode == 'A' || pCode == 'a') {
            countA++;
        }
        else if (pCode == 'B' || pCode == 'b') {
            countB++;
        }
        else if (pCode == 'C' || pCode == 'c') {
            countC++;
        }
        else
            cout << "wrong code for counter";

        totalPrice = calcTotalPrice(discPrice, taxPrice, netPrice);
        totalSales = totalSales + totalPrice;

        cout << "\nEnter 'Y' to proceed next person or 'N' to terminate (Y/N) : "; //sentinel input value
        cin >> decision;
        cout << "*************************************************************************\n\n";
    }
    // sentinelled controlled loop ends here

    displaySaleSummary(countA, countB, countC, totalSales);

    return 0;
}

string packageName(char pCode)
{

    string pName = "";

    if (pCode == 'A' || pCode == 'a')
        pName = "Pulau Langkawi";
    else if (pCode == 'B' || pCode == 'b')
        pName = "Pulau Pangkor";
    else if (pCode == 'C' || pCode == 'c')
        pName = "Pulau Perhentian";
    else
        pName = " ";

    return pName;
}

double calcPrice(char pCode, char meals, int numAdult, int numChild)
{

    int pAdult, pChild, pAdultMeals, pChildMeals;
    double netPrice;

    if (pCode == 'A' || pCode == 'a') {

        pAdult = 250;
        pChild = 200;
    }
    else if (pCode == 'B' || pCode == 'b') {

        pAdult = 350;
        pChild = 300;
    }
    else if (pCode == 'C' || pCode == 'c') {

        pAdult = 450;
        pChild = 400;
    }
    else {
        cout << "\nWrong Package Code";
        netPrice = 0;
        return netPrice;
    }

    switch (meals) {
    case 'Y':
    case 'y':
        pAdultMeals = 100;
        pChildMeals = 50;
        break;
    case 'N':
    case 'n':
        pAdultMeals = 0;
        pChildMeals = 0;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "\nwrong meals code";
        netPrice = 0;
        return netPrice;
    }

    netPrice = (numChild * pChild) + (numAdult * pAdult) + (numChild * pChildMeals) + (numAdult * pAdultMeals);
    return netPrice;
}

double calcTax(double netPrice)
{

    double taxPrice, tax;

    tax = 0.06;
    taxPrice = tax * netPrice;
    return taxPrice;
}

double calcDisc(double taxPrice, double netPrice)
{

    double disc, discPrice;

    if (taxPrice + netPrice >= 1500)
        disc = 0.10;
    else
        disc = 0;

    discPrice = disc * (taxPrice + netPrice);
    return discPrice;
}

double calcTotalPrice(double discPrice, double taxPrice, double netPrice)
{

    double totalPrice;
    totalPrice = (taxPrice + netPrice) - discPrice;
    return totalPrice;
}

void displayReceipt(double netPrice, double taxPrice, double discPrice, double totalPrice, string pName)
{

    netPrice = calcPrice(pCode, meals, numAdult, numChild);
    taxPrice = calcTax(netPrice);
    discPrice = calcDisc(taxPrice, netPrice);
    totalPrice = calcTotalPrice(discPrice, taxPrice, netPrice);
    pName = packageName(pCode);

    cout << "\n\nRECEIPT\n";
    cout << "---------------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "Customer's Name  : " << name << endl;
    cout << "Package Code     : " << pCode << endl;
    cout << "Package Name     : " << pName << endl;
    cout << "Add meals        : " << meals << endl;
    cout << "Price before tax : RM " << netPrice << endl;
    cout << "Total tax        : RM " << taxPrice << endl;
    cout << "Discount         : RM " << discPrice << endl;
    cout << "Total price      : RM " << totalPrice << endl;
    cout << "---------------------------------------------\n";
}

void displaySaleSummary(int countA, int countB, int countC, double totalSales)
{

    cout << "\n\nAI Travel & Tours" << endl;
    cout << "********************************" << endl;
    cout << "Package A   : " << countA << endl;
    cout << "Package B   : " << countB << endl;
    cout << "Package C   : " << countC << endl;
    cout << "Total Sales : " << totalSales << endl;
    cout << "********************************" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Do try and get out of the habit of `using namespace std`, just use the prefix to be clear what's being used, and *avoid global variables* unless you have no other option.

Comment: please provide a [mre] (with a focus on the minimal) with all the inputs and expected outputs

Comment: and your compiler should be warning you about many uninitialised variables

Comment: Most of the the variables passed to `displayReceipt` are uninitialized.  Turn on compiler warnings!

Comment: what the hell just happend i put some random input and it crashed.

Comment: Maybe you don't know the difference between pass by value and pass by reference and meant to pass some variables by reference. With that said, I think you should separate the functionality in `displayReceipt()` to only display and create some other function to do the calculations. You are passing uninitialized values to `displayReceipt()` and updating the copy of these values inside the function but in main() they remain uninitialized.

Comment: ***i put some random input and it crashed.*** This is a possibility because of the undefined behavior that exists by using variables that are uninitialized.

Comment: Unrelated: You have a lot of shadowing declarations in your code. It makes it really hard to read.

Comment: Perhaps you should reduce your code this code is too long, try putting a minimal reproducible example...

Answer (score 3):

A `NaN` will generally be caused either by divide by zero or uninitialised values.

In this case it is the latter. If your compiler doesn't warn you about uninitialised variables get a better compiler or make sure that warnings are enabled for your current compiler. Visual studio won't even compile your code:

```
error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'totalPrice' used
error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'discPrice' used
error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'taxPrice' used
error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'netPrice' used
error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'totalSales' used
```

Passing a variable to a function doesn't modify the value of that variable in the calling code. If you want this behaviour you need to pass your values by reference. You therefore need to change the declaration and definition of `displayReceipt` to:

```
void displayReceipt(double& netPrice, double& taxPrice, double& discPrice, double& totalPrice, string& pName) {
```

This gets rid of most of the uninitialised variables leaving just `totalSales` which needs to be initialised to `0`:

```
double netPrice, taxPrice, discPrice, totalSales = 0, totalPrice;
```

Though not strictly necessary as the values are never read I'd recommend initialising all of your variables, saves difficult to diagnose problems in future when your code changes:

```
double netPrice = 0, taxPrice = 0, discPrice = 0, totalSales = 0, totalPrice = 0;
```

Mostly as a personal preference I like to declare variables individually as it makes it easier to spot missing initialisers:

```
double netPrice = 0;
double taxPrice = 0;
double discPrice = 0;
double totalSales = 0;
double totalPrice = 0;
```

Comment: And here's a little example to show the effect of using uninitialized variables: https://godbolt.org/z/GxTp-i